# Why does this code compile without warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have no idea why this code complies :

```
int array[100];
array[-50] = 100; // Crash!!
```

...the compiler still compiles properly, without compiling errors, and warnings.

So why does it compile at all?

Comment: Because it is valid code. It is your responsibility to check that access into the array is within the correct bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array[-50] = 100;
```

Actually means here:

```
*(array - 50) = 100;
```

Take into consideration this code:

```
int array[100];
int *b = &(a[50]);
b[-20] = 5;
```

This code is valid and won't crash. Compiler has no way of knowing, whether the code will crash or not and what programmer wanted to do with the array. So it does not complain.

Finally, take into consideration, that you *should not rely* on compiler warnings while finding bugs in your code. Compilers *will not* find most of your bugs, they barely try to make some hints for you to ease the bugfixing process (sometimes they even may be mistaken and point out, that valid code is buggy). Also, the standard actually never *requires* the compiler to emit warning, so these are only an act of good will of compiler implementers.

Comment: Uh, yes, the compiler doesn't complain because it's simply not required to. That has nothing to do with where the accessed memory location is.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Compiler as a way of knowing, whether indexing an array will overrun the buffer: `warning C4789: buffer 'array' of size 400 bytes will be overrun; 4 bytes will be written starting at offset 800`. I modified the post though to be more clear as the memory is not exactly the issue here.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, you're completely right as far as I can tell, Spook. +1

Comment: The compiler may or may not "know" everything, true. It may not know that the assignment `array[-50] = 100;` is ever going to be attempted, true. But there's no requirement for compilers to catch undefined behavior even when it's possible to foresee it while compiling problematic code (e.g. `main()` could consist of only this assignment and this case would be a no-brainer for any decent compiler to catch).

Comment: Standard does not *require* compiler to emit warnings at all. Only two places in C++11 standard mention, that compiler implementations are *encouraged* to emit a warning in specific circumstances. The word 'warning' is used ~7 times in the whole spec, BTW if to believe Acrobat's search engine (talking about n3485).

Comment: See? We may speculate all we want, but there is just no requirement in the standard. That's the legal answer to the question. Removing -1.

Comment: That code (the 2nd block) is certainly not valid code. You assign a pointer to an int and then you are trying to use the subscript [] operator on an int??

Comment: This answer is just completely wrong. Downvotes are entirely appropriate. The reason the compiler doesn't complain is simply because nobody coded it to do so. They weren't required to and likely decided that it wasn't worth the effort since there were so many similar cases that couldn't be detected. It has nothing to do with not knowing if the code will crash or the code potentially being valid.

Comment: You see, I try to explain, *why* nobody coded it to do so. If the code is actually correct, why should compiler complain? And, did you miss the "Also, the standard actually never requires the compiler to emit warning, so these are only an act of good will of compiler implementers." part?

Comment: @Spook: The code is not "actually correct". Accessing an array out of bounds is UB.

Comment: From what I know, it is correct from compiler's perspective. If not, please cite the appropriate part of C++ standard, I will gladly learn something new.

Answer (score 6):

It compiles because the expression `array[-50]` is transformed to the equivalent

```
*(&array[0] + (-50))
```

which is another way of saying "take the memory address `&array[0]` and add to it -50 times `sizeof(array[0])`, then interpret the contents of the resulting memory address and those following it as an `int`", as per the usual pointer arithmetic rules. This is a perfectly valid expression where `-50` might really be any integer (and of course it doesn't need to be a compile-time constant).

Now it's definitely true that since here `-50` *is* a compile-time constant, and since accessing the minus 50th element of an array is almost always an error, the compiler could (and perhaps should) produce a warning for this.

However, we should also consider that detecting this specific condition (statically indexing into an array with an apparently invalid index) is something that you don't expect to see in real code. Therefore the compiler team's resources will be probably put to better use doing something else.

Contrast this with other constructs like `if (answer = 42)` which you *do* expect to see in real code (if only because it's so easy to make that typo) and which are hard to debug (the eye can easily read `=` as `==`, whereas that `-50` immediately sticks out). In these cases a compiler warning is much more productive.

Comment: Well, some compilers did put the effort (Clang did), and some compilers might have but the warning is deactivated by default... in a C++ world filled with macro expansions and template instantiations, you take as much warnings as you can.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I 'm all for the warning being given by default. Just trying to explain why some compilers may accept this code without any hiccup.

Answer (score 1):

[True compilers do](http://liveworkspace.org/code/KhrBw%241) (note: need to switch the compiler to clang 3.2, gcc is not user-friendly)

```
Compilation finished with warnings:
source.cpp:3:4: warning: array index -50 is before the beginning of the array [-Warray-bounds]
array[-50] = 100;
^ ~~~
source.cpp:2:4: note: array 'array' declared here
int array[100];
^
1 warning generated.
```

If you have a lesser (*) compiler, you may have to setup the warning manually though.

(*) ie, less user-friendly

Comment: I get:Compilation finished with warnings:
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:2:8: warning: variable 'array' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

Comment: I love clang's diagnostics, but in this case I don't think they help. Especially beginners will get a false sense of security ("the compiler will tell me when I'm accessing out of bounds!") when in all but the trivial cases the compiler has no way of finding out!

Comment: @user1271422 Change the compiler from g++ to clang.

Comment: Nevermind. I did not fix anything. LWS seems to not store information about the compiler in the snapshots :(

Comment: The link is not relevant, warning concerns issue not related to OP's question.

Comment: @us2012: I understand the feeling, but I still prefer to have as much checked at compilation time as possible.

Comment: @Spook: it's relevant but as R. Martinho Fernandes noticed liveworkspace does not seem to store the compiler used in the link; so you have to switch the compiler manually.

Comment: Ok, though that should have been stated as a comment to the link, as you did recently. Now everything's OK.

Comment: @Spook: I would have... if I had known :P

Comment: Yeah, LWS isn't user-friendly either :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not required to catch all potential problems at compile time. The C standard allows for undefined behavior at run time (which is what happens when this program is executed). You may treat it as a legal excuse not to catch this kind of bugs.

There are compilers and static program analyzers that can do catch trivial bugs like this, though.

Answer (score 0):

The number inside the brackets is just an index.  It tells you how many steps in memory to take to find the number you're requesting.  `array[2]` means start at the beginning of array, and jump forwards two times.

You just told it to jump backwards 50 times, which is a valid statement.  However, I can't imagine there being a good reason for doing this...

Comment: IMO, this doesn't answer the question at all.